# conforming form validation in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, form-validation

I need to confirm either my is validated or not.My form is

```
 <form action="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('abc_checkout/cart/placeorder'); ?>" method="post" id="confirm_order_form" class="info-static" onsubmit="return submitOrder();">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this script to your phtml file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //< ![CDATA[
        var customForm = new VarienForm('confirm_order_form');
    //]]>
</script>
```

Comment: Ok, how I would know, form is validated or not, customForm will be true or false, some thing like this

Comment: I  am already using it. I have to perform an action if form is validated.How can I do this?

Comment: if (customForm.validator && customForm.validator.validate())   
   {
     // if validation successful pass then
   }
  else
  {
  //magento validation fire
   }

Check more at here http://magentotutorialbeginners.blogspot.in/2014/03/custom-from-validation-in-magento.html

Comment: change theForm to dataForm


if (dataForm.validator && dataForm.validator.validate()){ $(".confirm-and-place-order").attr("disabled", true); $(".confirm-and-place-order").removeClass('enable'); } else{ //magento validation fire }

Comment: oops, that's my bad,